# ansible postgres add multiple extensions to database (nested loop)

Tags: postgresql, ansible

For creating PostgreSQL databases I use the following schema:

```yaml
---
postgres_database:
  - name: test
    user: test
    pass: secret

  - name: test2
    user: test2
    pass: secret
```

But now I need to add [extensions](https://www.postgresql.org/download/products/6-postgresql-extensions/) per database so I thought of using something like:

```yaml
---
postgres_database:
  - name: test
    user: test
    pass: secret
    extensions:
      - unaccent
      - pgcrypto
      - uuid-ossp

  - name: test2
    user: test2
    pass: secret

  - name: test3
    user: test3
    pass: secret
    extensions:
      - pgcrypto
```

The problem I have is that I can only pass an extension at a time, therefore wondering how could I loop over the items`postgres_database.extensions` within the `posgres_database` loop?

Currently, this works but only adds the first extension found:

```yaml
- name: add extensions
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_ext:
    name: "{{ item.extensions[0] }}"
    db: "{{ item.name }}"
  when: item.extensions is defined
  with_items:
    - "{{ postgres_database }}"
```

Any ideas about how could this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```yaml
- name: add extensions
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_ext:
    name: "{{ item.1 }}"
    db: "{{ item.0.name }}"
  loop: "{{ postgres_database | subelements('extensions', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

Refs:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/4/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-objects-and-subelements

Comment: Thanks, I just add to use single quotes: ```subelements('extensions', ```

Comment: Fixed. This was written on spot and not thoroughly tested as you've guessed. But as you probably already know, you are totally welcome and even encouraged to edit existing answers yourself, especially to fix a typo ;)